# How to set up hbm2ddl.auto with pure java configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am having a hard time finding materials which explain and outline on how to set up hbm2ddl.auto with pure java configuration in Spring 4. 
I am not using Spring Boot, as I want to get more understanding of Spring fundamentals. But of course, I want to avoid all XML files in my application.

So far I am able to configure and use my application, but I have to create tables manually. My attempt to set up hbm2ddl.auto is not going anywhere.

This is what I have:

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

```
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("--------------");
    System.out.println("Data Source Initialization");
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myeventmanager");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("******");
    System.out.println("--------------");
    System.out.println("Initialized");
    System.out.println(dataSource.getConnection());
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.ruruapps.domain"});
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public BeanPostProcessor persistenceTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

Properties hibernateProperties() {
    return new Properties() {
        {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
        }
    };
}
```

}

So what is the right way to have this configured?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement as follows.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "xxx.xxx.xxx" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.ws.ppp.pojo" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.automaticschema"));
    properties.put("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider",
            environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider"));
    properties.put("hibernate.search.default.indexBase",
            environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.search.default.indexBase"));

    return properties;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
    return txManager;
}
```

}

Comment: Would it build the database by just running the application on the server, or do I need to execute it in some other way? So far it did nothing.

Comment: I build the database by running the application. While creating sessionFactory it will create the tables on given database. Anyway you need to create the database first. This will create tables and the relationships only. Thanks

Comment: I do have it set up, I used other similar tools for .NET. 
Will adding Properties hibernateProperties() and the methods make it work, or do I have to change other beans too?

Comment: I used this for a spring MVC project. Apart from this I have AppConfig  class for configure spring mvc.`@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.aaa.bbb")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {` Apart from that the database properties are as follow  `jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost..
jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password = 
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.automaticschema = update` The property hibernate.automaticschema should be create or update

Answer (score 0):

It will be like .

```
            private Properties hibernateProperties() {
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
                properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
                properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
                properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.automaticschema"));
                properties.put("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider",
                        environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider"));
                properties.put("hibernate.search.default.indexBase",
                        environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.search.default.indexBase"));

                return properties;
            }
```

try this.